# Selecting values plotted on a scatter3 plot

Tags: matlab, 3d, scatter3d

I have a 3d matrix of 100x100x100. Each point of that matrix has assigned a value that corresponds to a certain signal strength. If I plot all the points the result is incomprehensible and requires horsepower to compute, due to the large amount of points that are painted.
The next picture examplify the problem (in that case the matrix was 50x50x50 for reducing the computation time):

[image]

```
[x,y,z] = meshgrid(1:50,1:50,1:50);
scatter3(x(:),y(:),z(:),5,strength(:),'filled')
```

I would like to plot only the highest values (for example, the top 10). How can I do it?

One simple solution that came up in my mind is to asign "nan" to the values higher than the treshold.
Even the results are nice I think that it must be a most elegant solution to fix it.
[image]

Comment: Actually I like to assign NaN values when ploting in data i just dont wanna plot... I think it is a nice approach!

Comment: @AnderBiguri Could be a fast solution, but even the values nan are not painted, at least as far as I am concerned, I notice how the representation is slow (I mean the rendering when rotating the view, for example), like if all the other points were painted.

Comment: mmm didn't know that, my data is usually smaller. Actually the answer given is not a bad idea neither

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape it into an nx1 vector. Sort that vector and take the first ten values.

```
num_of_rows = size(M,1)
V = reshape(M,num_of_rows,1); 
sorted_V = sort(V,'descend');
ind = sorted_V(1:10)
```

I am assuming that M is your 3D matrix. This will give you your top ten values in your matrix and the respective index. The you can use `ind2sub()` to get the `x,y,z`.